# R comulative distribution charts

Tags: r, plot, distribution, cdf

I'm quite a beginner at using R for visualization of data. I've generated comulative distribution chart with following code:

```
if (length(first$dtl) > 0) {first_cdf <- ecdf(first$dtl)} else first_cdf <- 0
cdf_range <- range(0, first$dtl, na.rm=TRUE)
plot(first_cdf, main="Distribution", xlab="Values", xlim=cdf_range, col="#76B727", cex.axis=0.8, pch=20)
```

With this I get

[image]

Now issue is that I would like to get clear line instead of dots connected with line. I've tried to change pch as well as lty parameter, but it seems there is no way to get clear line with those. Any idea how to solve this issues?

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: Hello Frank! Cheers for reponse. As I've stated, I've tested different pch and lty parameters (http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html), but I still can not get desired result, which is clear line. It becomes an issue when I add more lines to plot (more distributions) and it becomes very hard to spot which line is what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This disables the dots and adds vertical lines to make it continuous:

```
set.seed(1)
plot(ecdf(rnorm(100)), do.points=FALSE, verticals=TRUE)
```

[image]

Type `plot.ecdf` in at the R prompt to see the full function or `?plot.ecdf` for the help file (which directs further to `?plot.stepfun`). Even though you are calling vanilla `plot`, the `plot.ecdf` function is what's used, thanks to R's method dispatch, `?Methods`.

Comment: Thank you very much, d.points and verticals parameter did the trick perfectly! Cheers again!